# Why native speakers use “Could” in this sentence: “It’s too sour. I couldn’t take it anymore.”

Tags: modal-verbs

It’s too sour. I couldn’t take it anymore!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a few examples of the usages of 'could'.
It can be used for an ability in the past, possibilities in the future, for making requests, to name a few. [Source.](https://www.espressoenglish.net/difference-between-should-could-and-would/)

1. "Yesterday, I *could* not find my wallet anywhere – but this morning I found it."
2. "Last year, he *could* not speak English very well, but now he can."

In the case of your sentence, "It's too sour. I [did not have the strength to] endure it any more."